# Numpy not importing

Tags: python, pip

When i try to import numpy to my python file it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\src\Python\Raycast_Test_1\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

(i just found some things in the pip help thingy so i did them and this is what i got)
and when i do `pip search numpy` this shows up:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\marti\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 224, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\marti\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\search.py", line 62, in run
    pypi_hits = self.search(query, options)
  File "c:\users\marti\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\search.py", line 82, in search
    hits = pypi.search({'name': query, 'summary': query}, 'or')
  File "c:\users\marti\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1109, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "c:\users\marti\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1450, in __request
    response = self.__transport.request(
  File "c:\users\marti\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\xmlrpc.py", line 46, in request
    return self.parse_response(response.raw)
  File "c:\users\marti\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 1341, in parse_response
    return u.close()
  File "c:\users\marti\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\xmlrpc\client.py", line 655, in close
    raise Fault(**self._stack[0])
xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault -32500: "RuntimeError: PyPI's XMLRPC API has been temporarily disabled due to unmanageable load and will be deprecated in the near future. See https://status.python.org/ for more information.">
```

and when i do `pip check numpy` this shows up:

```
No broken requirements found.
```

i have tried uninstaling the installing numpy but that didnt fix it.
How do i fix this?

(note i am using the vscode terminal for this)

Comment: does your vscode point to the python that you have numpy installed for?

Comment: The search bit is unrelated to your issue. _PyPI_'s search API is temporarily out of order as far as I know. This is unrelated to your actual issue. -- @warped's suggestion is more likely to be a good meaningful lead. -- Make sure to use `python -m pip install ...` instead of `pip install ...`. -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 2):

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

or

```
pip install numpy --upgrade --ignore-installed
```

Answer (score -2):

Just to make sure you are running correct pip, try running "pip -V" or "pip --version", it gives you which version of python it refers to. Its also possible that you might have pip for say python 2.7, pip3 for python 3.6, and pip3.7 for python 3.7, if you have multiple versions of python installed. For simplicity you can set the most frequently used pip version as pip by setting an alias in ~/.bashrc. This is done by adding the following line in bashrc:

alias pip=pip3.6.

After this you can try and install the packages and import it swiftly.

Comment: Please do not recommend `pip3` script and things like that, instead it is always better to recommend to call _pip_'s executable module for a specific Python interpreter: `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip` -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: This is the exact reason I mentioned to first use pip -V. Using pythonx.x -m pip is just a user preference, I don't believe its a norm neither it is recommended anywhere. Even for the article it's based on a personal preference.

Comment: `python -m pip` is always more likely to give the expected results. Relying on `pip` scripts, or worse on alias is unreliable. Not a matter of opinion or personal preference.

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is. Any case python -m pip is same as just using pip. for your sake, if you really want to use this make sure to use pythonx.x -m pip

Comment: @anikjha You're simply incorrect. `/path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip ...` is **NOT** the same as running a `pip` or `pip3` or `pipX.Y` script or using a bash alias. All sorts of issues can arise when using scripts and aliases that can be solved by using `python -m pip`. They may appear the same to inexperienced users, but they are absolutely not the same, so don't say they are. Do some research so you can understand what you're talking about. This is a norm, and is recommended in the docs and elsewhere.

Comment: @MattDMo Please excuse my inexperience.

Comment: This is for example one of the weirdest cases of "`pip` does not do what you think it does" I encountered: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8010 -- There are many other cases like that. I wish the [`pip` scripts disappeared entirely](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3164) and the only way was `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip` (or at best `python -m pip` of course).